# How can I use "--percentage" in Inline CSS in React-TypeScript?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have a div with Inline-Style

`<div className="HalfArc" style={{ "--percentage": "75%" }}>`

and this works fine in my ReactJS project. It also works in my ReactTS project, but I get this TS2322-Error:

```
Type '{ "--percentage": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"--percentage"' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
```

I tried setting the "" in different position, but I have no idea how to get the error away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cast the style object to `React.CSSProperties`

```
const style = { "--percentage": "75%"} as React.CSSProperties;
<div className="HalfArc" style={style}>
```

Comment: Could you maybe tell me why this works?

Comment: because style is only accepting `CSSProperties` type. By default it doesn't have `--percentage` property. So by casting it to `CSSProperties` we are telling typescript that this is in fact a type of `CSSProperties`